# Search list of objects for maximum value by date

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I hope I can explain my situation well enough for some help.

Basically I have a list(ItemList) made up of ItemRows as follows

```
ItemRows
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemDate { get; set; }
        public string ItemPrice { get; set; }
```

Currently i am in a foreach loop which passes the current variables to another function in each iteration.  However when I pass the price I only ever want to pass the highest price per ItemDate.

```
foreach item in ItemList
{
    AnotherFunction(ItemId, ItemDate, MaxPriceByDate);
}
```

So if i had the following 4 rows of data....

```
123, 01/01/2015, $15
234, 01/01/2015, $20
345, 01/02/2015, $10
456, 01/02/2015, $5
```

here is how I want the loop to pass the info along:

```
first iteration:  123, 01/01/2015, $20
second iteration: 234, 01/01/2015, $20
third iteration:  345, 01/02/2015, $10
fourth iteration: 456, 01/02/2015, $10
```

basically I am looking for assistance on how to select the dollar amount from my list that the foreach loop is using but I only want it to ever select the highest amount by date from said list per iteration.

I hope this makes sense and I thank you for your assistance!!

Comment: you need an if else block

Comment: Why don't you pass `item` into `AnotherFunction` instead of specifying all the values on their own. Also the code you've provided won't compile due to a lack of braces, please show it correctly

Comment: It is data coming in from a flat file, but I might be able to work with the import of the data.  Not a bad idea, i will work with it a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(var item in ItemList)
{
    AnotherFunction(item.ItemId, item.ItemDate, ItemList.Where(x => x.ItemDate == item.ItemDate)
                                                        .OrderByDesc(z => Convert.ToInt32(z.ItemPrice.Replace("$", "")))
                                                                                 .First().ItemPrice);
}
```

Comment: As per my answer and some of the others the `ItemPrice` variable is a string and so will possibly need converting to an int

Comment: This recommendation worked out the best for me in my given scenario!  Thank You so much!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to group by the `ItemDate` property and handle this a bit differently. E.g.

```
 var grouped = (from r in rows
                 group r by r.ItemDate into g
                 select new { Date = g.Key, MaxPrice = g.Max(gg=>gg.ItemPrice)
                 Items = g})
```

This would give you a structure where each element has a Date, MaxPrice for that date and the items belonging to that date. With some small modifications in the looping you can fit this into your current structure.

Edit: as noted in another answer, you might have to convert the price to some number format if it's in string or same thing with the date property. I'd suggest do the conversion of string to date and number before getting into this logic.

Comment: See my answer for the conversion logic to an int, if needed

Answer (score 3):

If all you're asking for is the `MaxPricePerDate` you can use the following linq function:

```
int nMaxPrice = ItemList.Where(i => i.ItemDate == item.ItemDate
                        .Max(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.ItemPrice));
```

Also if the string does contain the `$` symbol this will need to be stripped first like `i.ItemPrice.Replace("$", "");`

The `Convert` call is needed to convert the string to an int, however it is dangerous as if the string is not in the correct format an exception can be thrown. Consider also looking into `Int32.TryParse();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` to find the max price for the current data. This is probably not the most efficient way but it will work:

```
  foreach(var item in itemList)
  {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.ItemId, item.ItemDate, itemList.Where(i => i.ItemDate == item.ItemDate).Max(d => d.ItemPrice));
  }
```

Comment: This is similar to my answer but note that `ItemPrice` is a string not an int and so will need to be converted.

Comment: You right and you where just a few seconds earlier :-)

Comment: I know I wasn't complaining of copying :)